# Search flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am displaying a list of contacts from my address book in a flatlist and want to be able to search the list. The issue is that initially the list is empty and I get an error because it is trying to filter undefined.

If I type a name though it works and if I delete my search query it then shows all users. I would like it do this from the start. I am not sure why it is undefined intially, perhaps because the state has not yet been set.

```
const AddContactScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState();
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [filteredContactList, setFilteredContactList] = useState(contacts);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
          sort: Contacts.SortTypes.FirstName,
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
          setContacts(data);
        }

        const newContacts = contacts.filter((item) =>
          item.name.includes(query)
        );
        setFilteredContactList(newContacts);
      }
    })();
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <Screen>
      <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.searchField}
              placeholder="Search"
              onChangeText={setQuery}
              value={query}
            />
          </View>
        }
        data={filteredContactList}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
        keyExtractor={(contact) => contact.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={item.name}
            onPress={() => console.log("contact selected", item)}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Screen>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchContainer: {
    padding: 15,
  },
  searchField: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default AddContactScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState();
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
const [filteredContactList, setFilteredContactList] = useState(contacts);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
          sort: Contacts.SortTypes.FirstName,
        });

        setLoading(false);
        setContacts(data.length ? data : []);
       
      }
    })();
  }, [query]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(contacts.length) {
     const newContacts = contacts.filter((item) =>
       item.name.includes(query)
     );
     setFilteredContactList(newContacts);
   }
}, [contacts])

if(loading) return <p>loading...</p>;
if(!contacts.length) return <p>No data found</>;


// your rest of the code.
```

NOTE: i have written the code from the imagination. You might need to do some tweak.

Comment: This is a good idea as well, but why do you have [query] in the first useEffect render? I don't think it is necessary upon first render.

Comment: Well. It has some few more work around. suppose the url is `http://localhost:3000?search=myItem` and someone directly landed on the url. then `const [query, setQuery] = useState("");` will be  ```const [query, setQuery] = useState(window.location.search || '');``` though the search value window.location.search need to work. I addition he is doing `onChangeText={setQuery}` to change the query. so it's require.

Comment: It's a React Native app, not a react app so there won't be a url. I am using Expo to show the contacts from my address book and searching that.

Comment: my bad. In that case. You dont need to use useEffect at all for the first render. Create a fn `onChangeText={setQuery}` instead of setQuery and pass the query value to the fn and fetch and set the datas.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice would be to set your initial value of contacts to an empty array []

So your state would be

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Well spotted, thanks! That took the error away but by list is still initially empty

Comment: Maybe because it's an async function it takes time to respond. Do you see the populated list getting rendered on its own after a while? If so you'll have to show some loading indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use useEffect when component mounts to get initial contacts and handle the query in a separate function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getInitialContacts()
  }, []);

const getInitialContacts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
          sort: Contacts.SortTypes.FirstName,
        });

        setLoading(false);
        setContacts(data.length ? data : []);
       
      }
    });
}
```

you can use another function that you call when text is entered:

```js
const handleQuery = (query) => {
  const newContacts = contacts.filter((item) =>
          item.name.includes(query)
        );
  setFilteredContactList(newContacts);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call handleQuery ?

Comment: you call it in `onChangeText` of `TextInput`

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. So far only using the 2 useEffect hooks works

Comment: Check what state you use for data in `flatList` as, with this code `contacts`  should be `data`, you can try to use `flatlist` `extradata`  with the filteredContactList. Of corse  if you want to debug this solution.